# AWS SFTP Transfer remote open("/file"): Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a SFTP server setup in AWS Transfer Family tied to a S3 bucket and when the user tries uploading to it without IP restriction, it works. However, when IP restriction is added, we get a `Permission denied` error. (Some information has been deidentified for privacy reasons)

```
sftp> put file.pdf
Uploading file.pdf to /file.pdf
remote open("/file.pdf"): Permission denied
sftp>
```

Policy without IP restriction:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:XXXXX:key/XXXXX"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::data/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::data"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

File upload successful. Cloudwatch logs without IP restriction:

```
2022-08-03T18:49:56.945-05:00   username.XXXX  CONNECTED SourceIP=X.X.X.X User=username HomeDir=LOGICAL Client=SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 Role=arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/TransferBucketRW Kex=ecdh-sha2-nistp256 Ciphers=chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com

2022-08-03T18:50:26.134-05:00   username.XXXX  OPEN Path=/data/uploads/file.pdf Mode=CREATE|TRUNCATE|WRITE

2022-08-03T18:50:26.240-05:00   username.XXXX  CLOSE Path=/data/uploads/file.pdf BytesIn=347971
```

Policy with IP restriction

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:XXXX:key/XXXX"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::data/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::data"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "X.X.X.X/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

File upload failed. Cloudwatch Logs with IP restriction

```
2022-08-03T18:59:14.498-05:00   username.XXXX CONNECTED SourceIP=X.X.X>X User=username HomeDir=LOGICAL Client=SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 Role=arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/TransferBucketRW Kex=ecdh-sha2-nistp256 Ciphers=chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com

2022-08-03T18:59:39.323-05:00   username.XXXX  ERROR Message="Access Denied" Operation=OPEN Path=/data/uploads/file.pdf Mode=CREATE|TRUNCATE|WRITE RequestID=P9S2XW6FNMAW9T4T S3ExtendedRequestID=Omk8mugElCEwQpv1zXQtflAk8kEnky2/LrsetgW03js4g64ZI2XCjp6i8zgQvDZBf+hAp8ZdLS0=

2022-08-03T18:59:39.323-05:00   username.XXXX  ERROR Message="Access denied"
```

I can confirm that the IP in the policy matched the `SourceIP` seen in the Cloudwatch Logs. Wondering if I need add this IP restriction in the Trust Policy of the role in addition to this IAM policy.

Comment: The file is being created by the AWS Transfer service, not the end-user. Therefore, it would need the IP address of AWS Transfer in the policy. However, that probably defeats the purpose of using an IP restriction. Instead, see: [Use IP whitelisting to secure your AWS Transfer for SFTP servers | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/use-ip-whitelisting-to-secure-your-aws-transfer-for-sftp-servers/)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, we did take a look at that but we do not have a VPC setup (and would like to avoid doing it that way) since we just need a simple SFTP server deployed relatively quickly. Is there a way to IP restrict access to the server itself (rather than the bucket) without VPC/SG?

Comment: Might be useful: [Securing AWS Transfer Family with AWS Web Application Firewall and Amazon API Gateway | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/securing-aws-transfer-family-with-aws-web-application-firewall-and-amazon-api-gateway/) Apparently, you can use WAF's capabilities if you're using a custom authorizer with API Gateway. Might be a way of adding a layer of protection.

Comment: We got IP restriction to work by creating a VPC/Security group setup.